# problem to Use : Android React Native & @react-native-community/art

Tags: android, react-native

I want use component shadow with "https://github.com/tokkozhin/react-native-neomorph-shadows.git" im my Project , but can't run my project with this dependency : #  `@react-native-community/art`

npm start

**Error :**

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
**A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_art'.**
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':@react-native-community_art:classpath'.
> Could not find builder-3.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar
> Could not find bundletool-0.5.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.5.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.5.0/bundletool-0.5.0.jar
> Could not find aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
```

**I have done these things too :**
`npm i react-native-neomorph-shadows`
`npm install @react-native-community/art --save`

**Update this files :**
`android/settings.gradle`
`android/app/build.gradle`
`android/app/src/main/.../MainApplication.java`

**Do you have any ideas؟؟؟**